# Passing a Javascript Array through JQuery AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

```
$('#button').live('click', function () {
    values_array = [];
    $('.field').each(function () {
        values_array.push = $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        data: {
            array_a: values_array
        },
        type: 'POST',

        success: function (data) {
            $('#div').html(data);
        }
    });
});


//page.php
echo $_POST['array_a'] . "<br/>"; //The line break echos, but nothing else
```

A.) Do I need to iterate through each class with `$.each` in order to create a proper array, and

B.) Why doesn't php echo it?

Comment: Did you tried to put `array_a` in brackets - `data: { "array_a" : values_array }`?

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST)` ?

Comment: `Array ( )`, as expected

Comment: check out what's the content of values_array after each() with console.log()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

`values_array.push = $(this).val();`

to:

`values_array.push($(this).val());`

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

`.push` is a method which you have used like a property try instead

```
values_array = [];
   $('.field').each(function() {
      values_array.push($(this).val());
   });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push